# SQL command for the last value. Additionally with a search ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to search my database via SQL command for the last value and for a given ID.

The ID works so well:

```
SELECT * FROM 'tem2' WHERE macid = '*'.
```

Unfortunately, if I add `LAST ( SELECT LAST * FROM...)` it does not work anymore.

Comment: I assume the single quotes around `tem2` are a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "last" value unless a column specifies the ordering.  Let me assume you have one.

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tem2
WHERE macid = '*'
ORDER BY <ordering col>
LIMIT 1;
```

The ordering column would be a creation date or auto-incremented id.

Comment: 'tem2' is a string

Comment: yes i have activated AUTO_INCREMENT :) tem2 is a table. 

unfortunately it spits out an error: 
Error in the SQL syntax. Please look up the correct syntax in the manual at '<ordering col> ?

Comment: @RaylanNachti . . . You need to put in the name of the column there.